# Process continues to run after receiving uncaught SIGINT (Ctrl-C from terminal)

Tags: linux, process, signals, gnu-make

I am trying to interrupt some running processes with `Ctrl-C` from the terminal in Centos7; some do, some don't.

One of the problematic processes (Process-A) is a GNU makefile with nothing fancy; just the usual single file make system. The other (Process-B) is an C application that listens on TCP socket.

Following are my observations when I run (and try to terminate) some of these problematic processes:

- Process-A doens't die with `Ctrl-C`. When stared with strace -f and `Ctrl-C` is pressed, strace detaches from of the sub processes and *strace quits* but Process-A continues without strace logs (this is very strange).
- Process-B doesn't die with `Ctrl-C`. When started with `strace -f`, catches SIGINT and and terminates as expected.
- Process-B doesn't die with `Ctrl-C`. When suppressed to background and sent a SIGINT externally (`kill -s SIGINT PID`) still discards it while a SIGTERM kills it.

**Additional Details:**

1. With a test program I verified that my terminal is sending a SIGINT to the process (the test program does exit).
2. In neither of the processes, I am manually capturing any signals.
3. Tried with multiple terminal applications to observe identical behavior.

Need some clarity on how these signals are cascaded and what I am missing here. How does one go about debugging such issues?

**Update1:**

I run `grep 'search_string'` to make grep wait for input in `STDIN`. Now I'm unable to close it with `Ctrl-C`. Beginning to wonder if its an environment specific issue.

**Update2:**

After some work, discovered that sourcing RVM script as below is causing this issue.

```
if [ -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]; then
  source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
  export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Process-A does not die with Ctrl-C but strace does (this is very strange)

This is not at all strange, `strace` is not handling the signal but Process-A is. The signal that results from <kbd>control+c</kbd> is sent to all processes in the foreground process group (unless [the terminal](http://man.openbsd.org/man4/termios.4) is in some other mode) which for the test case below includes `strace` and `perl`. `strace` exits but the signal-ignoring process continues to run until killed by some other means.

```
% strace perl -E '$SIG{INT}="IGNORE";while(1){say $$;sleep 1}'
...
% 9520
9520
9520
kill9520
 9520
%
```

> I run grep 'search_string' to make grep wait for input in STDIN. Now I'm unable to close it with Ctrl-C.

This does point to a shell configuration problem; `grep` likely has inherited a signal handler from a parent process which in this case would be your shell. I have a [`blocksig`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/signal/blocksig.c) script that illustrates this case:

```
% grep asdf
^C
% blocksig grep asdf
^C^C^C^C^C^]^\zsh: quit       blocksig grep asdf
%
```

However in your case it's your shell and not `blocksig` that is the parent process. What happens when you switch to some other shell or start your shell without reading the typical `rc` files? Do you have any `trap` setup or customized job or job monitoring configuration in your shell configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed my .bashrc and I was able to kill grep with `Ctrl+C`. So I suppose that is causing the issue. I isolated the contents of the file few at a time to narrow down the exact cause without much luck. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: did you find anything related to `trap` (or a `source` or `.` file that includes `trap`?) otherwise it might be some `shopt` that could differ between a bare config and yours

Comment: Finally I found that sourcing RVM script at `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` was causing this issue. Should I report this to the RVM maintainer?

Comment: you probably should edit your post to show what the offending code looks like. reporting it may also be a good idea, as whatever that code is is kinda breaking things

Comment: I have updated the question with the lines that caused the issue. Also, I will try to reach the RVM maintainer.